# Apexchart-reactjs library doesn't support arabic language in the labels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am using Apexchart-reactjs library to draw line chart, the problem is i need to make the y labels in arabic language but i think it doesn't support that,
i have contacting the developer of the library on github but there is a delay in responding,
So i decided to ask you if there is a solution for this problem

screenshot to illustrate the problem for you :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the same issue with both Apex charts and am charts. Some of these libraries use letter-spacing in their CSS or in the templates they are packaged within and this causes an issue for most RTL languages.

Here is a fix:

```
    <body style="letter-spacing:normal !important">
```

or in your top level CSS file:

```
    #yourchartdiv {
         letter-spacing:normal;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. 
You've saved me

)))